# How to synchronize video files with ionic hybrid app and server

Tags: playframework, architecture, synchronization, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I have an architectural question. In my upcoming hybrid mobile application I am about to offer user content documents with text and video clips. These documents are fetched from server and saved in the app.

There will be also user authentication and document authorization.

I am planning to use ionic framework and create the backend with play framework.

Is it a good solution to go for pouchDB and couchDB to achieve storing documents in the app when they are loaded from the server for example during app start? Video files can be large so video files could be loaded and cached in pouch "manually" by user's selection in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have done research and end up using the architectural design presented. I have this follow up guestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912612/how-to-handle-document-updates-in-couchdb-when-i-use-database-per-user-approach